# What is the equivalent in Swift of offsetof(struct, member) in C?

Tags: swift, memory, struct, offset

Here's a struct in Swift:

```
struct A {
    var x
    var y
    var z
}
```

What should I do to get the offset of `y` in the struct `A`, just like `offsetof(A, y)` in C?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

[`MemoryLayout.offset(of:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/memorylayout/2996397-offset) 
was added in Swift 4.2, with the implementation of

- [SE-0210 Add an offset(of:) method to MemoryLayout](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0210-key-path-offset.md)

Example:

```
struct A {
    var x: Int8
    var y: Int16
    var z: Int64
}

MemoryLayout.offset(of: \A.x) // 0
MemoryLayout.offset(of: \A.y) // 2
MemoryLayout.offset(of: \A.z) // 8
```

*Remark:* This should work as well, but (as of Swift 4.2) does not compile (bug [SR-8335](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8335)):

```
MemoryLayout<A>.offset(of: \.y)
// error: Expression type 'Int?' is ambiguous without more context
```

Answer (score 5):

Swift doesn't currently define a standard memory layout for structs defined in Swift. That means any code you write to decompose a struct via pointer math is not guaranteed to work on future releases of, or even minor updates to the Swift compiler. (As @robmayoff notes, this is part of Swift getting a stable ABI, one of the Swift project's goals for version 5 this year.)

If your struct is defined in C and imported via a bridging header, though, Swift respects the C binary layout of its memory. In such cases, the [`MemoryLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/memorylayout) type provides equivalents to the C `sizeof` operator and similar utilities. There's still no `offsetof` equivalent, but you can do the pointer math yourself by adding the `stride`s of the member types in C declaration order.

For example, the Apple docs for [`SCNGeometrySource`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scngeometrysource) have an example of creating a 3D object from a buffer of interleaved vertex/normal/texture-coordinate data. But it's (currently) written in ObjC, using `sizeof` and `strideof` to tell SceneKit where to find each kind of data in the buffer. The Swift equivalent would use `MemoryLayout<Float>.size` in place of `sizeof(float)`, etc, and in place of `offsetof(MyVertex, nx)` you'd need to observe that there are three floats in the struct before the `nx` field and write `MemoryLayout<Float>.stride * 3`.

Comment: Thanks for the great answers!

Comment: Actually, the issue I just encountered in OpenGL-ES was very similar to what you have described in your last paragraph.  But the code is some kind of ugly and inflexible :(

Answer (score 2):

You can't get the offset of `y` in a reliable way, because Swift does not yet support that operation. Eventually, there will be support after “ABI stability” is implemented.

The current recommended approach is to define the `struct` in C, and also define C functions to return the offsets of the fields.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply :)